# How do I add two strings together in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, string, syntax

Say you have this array with the following inputs:

```
$relations["fname"] = 'firstname';
$relations["lname"] = 'lastname';
```

Now I would like to input the two above values into the following (I know the syntax is incorrect but I would like the firstname and lastname strings to become one string and input into the secondarray):

```
$secondarray["name"] = $relations["fname"] + $relations["lname"];
```

Comment: The string concatenation operator is `.`.

Comment: @deceze that's an answer not a comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$secondarray["name"] = $relations["fname"] + $relations["lname"];
```

Should be

```
$secondarray["name"] = $relations["fname"] . $relations["lname"];
```

The `+` operator is not overloaded to concatenate strings in PHP.

Comment: That would give you "firstnamelastname" instead of "firstname lastname".

Comment: Thanks perfect! Thanks for the explanation about the + operator!

Comment: @vascowhite yes you are right but you can do it like this $rel["fname"].' '.$rel["lname"]

Answer (score 5):

just for the heck of it :-)

```
$relations["fname"] = 'firstname';
$relations["lname"] = 'lastname';
$secondarray["name"] = implode($relations," ");
```

Comment: Only if there isn't also $relations["mname"] or $relations["suffix"] or $relations["mphone"] in there somewhere, as well.

Comment: Thanks I am sure that would work as well, I have more than just the fname and lname in that array though so it would add everything to it I am sure and probably not what I want...Is this better than using . though?

Comment: @user1748026: It was just meant to illustrate that while strings _are_ concatenated using `.` operator in PHP, if you do have an array with multiple values that you need to convert into a string, you can use the `implode` function. It might not be very useful for your current use-case. But if you just consider the title of your question, it will make sense. And hey who knows? next time you have a lengthy array to convert you can use this function instead of all those concatenations :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation as I might use it in the future!